# set any process that takes 50ms or longer is logged in mongod.conf

Tags: mongodb

I wanna set any process that takes 50ms or longer is logged

I am aware of the below methods
db.setProfilingLevel
db.setLoglevel

mongod --profile 2 --slowms 50

But i wanna set it from /etc/mongod.conf
any suggestions?

Comment: I wanna set any process that takes 50ms or longer is logged , How do i configure this mongod.conf

Comment: Equivalent server profiling defaults can be set in the [`operationProfiling` section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operationprofiling-options) of your MongoDB configuration file (`--slowms` is `operationProfiling.slowOpThresholdMs`).

Answer (score 4):

We can update mongod configuration file with the below configuration

```
operationProfiling:
  slowOpThresholdMs: 50
```